# Calculating vertical vapor flux divergence from WRF model output using NCL

Tags: wrf, moisture-flux

I want to find the vertical vapour flux divergence (1/g * ∂(qw)/∂z) as mentioned in section 3.3 of this paper https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/20/5559/2020/#section5

From few discussions here, I tried to plot using ncl:

shum        =   mixhum_ptrh(pres,temp,rh,2) ; specific humidity in kg/kg

uq          =   ua * shum                           ;vapor flux

vq          =   va * shum

div = uv2dvG_Wrap(uq,vq)

My query is :

The unit of div that I am getting is in 1/s. But what I intend to get is vertical vapor flux convergence in g  h−1  m−2  hPa−1.

Are the both same or else how can I reach this unit. Kindly explain.

I am wondering if I am wrong totally!

Looking forward to any kind of help.

Thank you